# Converting a download function to be async

Tags: android, asynchronous, xamarin, android-bitmap, webclient

I am using `Xamarin` and I am downloading many images for a `GridView`.

Here is my code that I call for each image:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUri(string uri)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        }
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

Can someone please help me to make this code above asynchronous?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Android version? 4.8+ or below 4.8?

Comment: My Xamarin.Android version is 4.8+

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Async / Await](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/) with `WebClient`'s `DownloadDataTaskAsync` method to make your code asynchronous as [defined here with example](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/AsyncImageAndroid/):

```
async Task<Bitmap> downloadAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs ea)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  var url = new Uri("http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA15416.jpg");
  byte[] bytes = null;

  try{
    bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
  }
  catch(TaskCanceledException){
    // Exception
    return;
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    // Exception
    return;
  }

  Bitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

  return bitmap;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent C# AsyncTask which can be found in JAVA :

```
public class DownloadBitmap : AsyncTask
{
    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
         //launch loading dialog.. before your main task
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
         //download your Bitmap
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
         //return your Bitmap to update the UI
    }
}
```

=> Additional informations [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/)